# Using attributes of nodes as labels in NetworkX

Tags: python, list-comprehension, networkx

I am using NetworkX to represent some graphs. My nodes are named using ids, but when I draw the graph, I would like to use the string saved in a attribute of the node. Here how the nodes look like:

```
print( graph.nodes(data=True)[:3], type(graph.nodes(data=True)),)
[('#per466', {'NormalizedName-sp': 'Mahlón', 'type': 'person', 'Gender': 'male'}), ('#per95', {'NormalizedName-sp': 'Isaí', 'type': 'person', 'Gender': 'male'}), ('#per14', {'NormalizedName-sp': 'Dios', 'type': 'person', 'Gender': 'none'})] <class 'list'>
```

I have tried access this information with a list comprehension and then use it the draw_networkx function:

```
specific_labels = [dictionary['NormalizedName-sp'] for item in graph.nodes(data=True) for dictionary in item[1].items()]
nx.draw_networkx(graph, pos, labels = specific_labels, width = widths, font_size=13, alpha=0.1, edge_color="blue", node_shape=None)
```

The list comprehension doesn't work and I am pretty sure that there is a easier way to access specific attributes and use it as labels. Any help, **please?**

Update!:

Ok, I figured it out:

```
labels = nx.get_node_attributes(graph,'NormalizedName-sp')
nx.draw_networkx(graph, pos, labels = labels, width = widths, font_size=13, alpha=0.1, edge_color="blue", node_shape=None)
```

It was easier than the list comprehension...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok, I figured it out:
`labels = nx.get_node_attributes(graph,'NormalizedName-sp');     nx.draw_networkx(graph, pos, labels = labels, width = widths, font_size=13, alpha=0.1, edge_color="blue", node_shape=None);
`
It was easier than the list comprehension...

Comment: You should add that as the "answer" to your question so it's easier for future users to find.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I have just done it. Thanks!